# Django to Heroku error: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: django, heroku

I keep getting this error when deploying a Django app to Heroku via the Heroku CLI

gunicorn the_weather.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\martin kalax\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\users\martin kalax\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\MARTIN KALAX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\gunicorn.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "c:\users\martin kalax\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\wsgiapp.py", line 9, in 
from gunicorn.app.base import Application
File "c:\users\martin kalax\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\base.py", line 11, in 
from gunicorn import util
File "c:\users\martin kalax\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\util.py", line 9, in 
import fcntl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'

Comment: what command you passed?

Comment: 'File "c:\users\martin kalax\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py"'—why is a Windows-style path being shown here? Heroku doesn't run Windows.